How to implement a list item component with adaptive width to fill the parent container
The result I have right now is like this.

The result I need is like this.

Here is my code:
<template>
    <t-space direction="vertical">
        <div class="user-container">
            <t-avatar size="100px" :image="avatarImage" alt="用户头像" shape="circle"/>
            <span class="UserName">{{ userName }}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <t-head-menu v-model="menuValue" @change="changeHandler">
                <t-menu-item value="item1">点评</t-menu-item>
                <t-divider layout="vertical"/>
                <t-menu-item value="item2">关注用户</t-menu-item>
                <t-divider layout="vertical"/>
                <t-menu-item value="item3"> 关注课程 </t-menu-item>
            </t-head-menu>
        </div>
        <t-divider style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"/>
        <div style="width:839px">
            <ProfileReviewList v-if="menuValue === 'item1'"/>
            <ProfileCourseList v-if="menuValue === 'item3'"/>
            <ProfileFollowUserList v-if="menuValue === 'item2'"/>
        </div>
    </t-space>
</template>

When I modify width:839px as width:100%,it works badly. But for compatibility, I cannot use a fixed width.
Here is ProfileFollowUserList.vue
<template>
    <UserItemList style="width: 100%;"/>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup name="">
    import UserItemList from '@/components/userItem/UserItemList.vue';
    
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
    
</style>


Here is UserItemList.vue
<template>
    <div class="userItemList">
        <UserItem
            v-for="(user, index) in users"
            :key="index"
            :avatarImage="user.avatarImage"
            :userName="user.userName"
            :numberOfNewReviews="user.numberOfNewReviews"
        />
    </div>
</template>


Here is UserItem.vue
<template>
    <div class="userItem">
        <div class="block1">
            <t-avatar :image="avatarImage" size="50px" style="margin-right: 20px"/>
            <div>
                <span class="username">{{ userName }}</span>
                <div class="tip-wrapper">
                    <span class="tip">{{ numberOfNewReviews }}条新点评</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <t-button v-if="follow" theme="default" @click="cancelFollow">已关注</t-button>
        <t-button v-if="!follow" theme="primary" @click="goonFollow" style="padding: 0 22px">关注</t-button>
    </div>
</template>


<style scoped lang="scss">
    .userItem {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-top: 5;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .block1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .tip-wrapper {
        background-color: #f6f8f9;
        border-radius: 8px;
        padding: 0px 10px;
        margin-top: 5px;    
    }
    .tip {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #666;
    }
</style>

Perhaps the problem lies in how I extend the length of the UserItem so that it can fill the outer container.

"width:100%,it works badly", how so? I created simplified demo, it shows 100% width achieving the desired effect.  Regardless of the tab content you want it to take up all the space that the content on the right-hand side is not.

You can see in the GIF that it’s not working well. I think the issue might be because my code isn’t complete enough, so I’ve re-edited the question. Your demo doesn’t seem to reproduce my problem well, or maybe I didn’t understand your demo. If it’s the latter, could you explain it to me?

The demo in the first comment, by yoduh, is exactly what you need and what you want - it solves your problem, and nothing else would solve it. In his example, ".content1" is your whole first block of code. ".content2" is the grey vertical column on the right in your screenshots; it is not shown in your code blocks. Nothing on the level below, like in your ProfileFollowUserList.vue, should matter at all. Start with replicating and understanding his example and how it is relevant to your code. I don't know how to explain it better, but be assured: he understood your problem and solved it.

I apologize for not understanding the demo at first, but I have resolved the issue. As before, it was the  component causing the problem. I removed it and rewrote the styles. Thank you for your help!
